# Troubles enabling hid with android custom kernel

Tags: android, kernel, hid, s6

i hope you're doing all good,

To be short i installed kali-nethunter on my device :

Samsung Galaxy S6 (exynos7420) (SM-G920W8) running android 7.0 (nougat) rooted with TWRP and Magisk
Kernel version 3.10.61 , architecture aarch64 (which i believe is the same as arm64)

Everything looks to be working fine except for the HID part :

- when i click USB Arsenal i get an alert that says : "Your kernel does not support USB ConfigFS"
- when i try to launch an attack with HID Attacks i get an alert that says : "HID interfaces not enabled or something wrong with the permission of /dev/hidg*, make sure they are enabled and permissions are granted as 666"

I do not have any file corresponding to hidg*  file in the /dev directory so i tried to build a custom kernel that supports HID.
(kernel source : https://github.com/jdawg82/StockS6-Nethunter             /!\ Nougat branch)

As mentioned in the official documentation ( https://www.kali.org/docs/nethunter/nethunter-kernel-6-config-5/ ) in order the achieve that i need to :

```
select “Generic serial bulk in/out” (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_SERIAL=y)
select “Abstract Control Model (CDC ACM)" (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ACM=y)
select “Object Exchange Model (CDC OBEX)" (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_OBEX=y)
select “Network Control Model (CDC NCM)" (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_NCM=y)
select “Ethernet Control Model (CDC ECM)" (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM=y)
select “Ethernet Control Model (CDC ECM) subset” (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_ECM_SUBSET=y)
select “RNDIS” (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_RNDIS=y)
select “Ethernet Emulation Model (EEM)" (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_EEM=y)
select “Mass Storage” (CONFIG_USB_CONFIGFS_MASS_STORAGE=y)
```

which kind of confirms the configFS alert

The problem is i do not have these options in my kernel menuconfig so i am completely lost and in need of help.

Any answer would be much appreciated even if not conclusive.

Thanks for your time !